# Searching a text file for every word in a list and print the lines

Tags: python, list

I would like to search a .txt file for a "list" of words and print any line in the txt that contains any words in the wordlist.

I firstly used `.split()` to split out the `raw_input` (called `userInput`) and got a wordlist. After that I filtered the current wordlist with another blacklist wordlist and got a final filtered wordlist. I want to search the text file for any of its words in this case.

```
exWords = ['Who', 'How', 'What', 'How many', 'How much', 'am', 'is', 'are', '?', '!']
while True:
    userInput = raw_input("> ")
    uqWords = userInput.split()
    fqWords = [word for word in uqWords if not any(bad in word for bad in exWords)]
```

After I took `userInput` apart with `.split()` and called it `uqWords` I filtered them from any words in the `exWords` list and called the output `fqWords`. Now I want to search `Database.txt` for any word in the `fqWords` list and print the lines.

to be specified; my full code is:

```
import time
import random

Error = ["Sorry, I don't understand.", "I don't get it"]
exWords = ['Who', 'How', 'What', 'How many', 'How much', 'am', 'is', 'are', '?', '!']
R = "Rel > "

while True:
    userInput = raw_input("> ")
    uqWords = userInput.split()
    fqWords = [word for word in uqWords if not any(bad in word for bad in exWords)]
    DB = open("Database.txt")
    for line in DB:
        if fqWords in line:
            print (R + line[:-1])
    CDB = open("CodeDB.txt")
    for code in CDB:
        if fqWords in code:
            print (R + code[:-1])
            break
        if fqWords not in (code and line):
            randomError = random.choice(Error)
            print (R + (randomError))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this function:

```
def search_for_lines(filename, words_list):
    words_found = 0
    with open(filename) as db_file:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(db_file):
            if any(word in line for word in words_list):
                print(line_no, ':', line)
                words_found += 1
    return words_found
```

Just pass the filename and the list of words you want to search and it will print the line number, together with the line content, and will return how many lines were found with any of the words. [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) will give you tuples of the line number and the line itself as the file iterates over every line.

To add this to your existing code and search thought both files, you will need to first declare it, and then call it just after your assignment of `fqWords` like so:

```
import random

def search_for_lines(filename, words_list):
    words_found = 0
    with open(filename) as db_file:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(db_file):
            if any(word in line for word in words_list):
                print(line_no, ':', line)
                words_found += 1
    return words_found

Error = ["Sorry, I don't understand.", "I don't get it"]
exWords = ['Who', 'How', 'What', 'How many', 'How much', 'am', 'is', 'are', '?', '!']
R = "Rel > "

while True:
    userInput = raw_input("> ")
    uqWords = userInput.split()
    fqWords = [word for word in uqWords if not any(bad in word for bad in exWords)]
    search_for_lines("Database.txt", fqWords)

    words_found = search_for_lines("CodeDB.txt", fqWords)

    if words_found > 0:
        break
    else:
        randomError = random.choice(Error)
        print (R + (randomError))
```

Comment: It did not help sir, Actually my full code is not just that

Comment: You print line numbers, is that ok?

Comment: @ZaidRiyadhAl-Rahawi I've edited the answer with an example to use it with the code provided in the question.

Comment: I want it to search two files actually for the list of words I specified, if it does not find any of those words, it returns with a random error.

Comment: Because in this case I need it to search in two files

Comment: Sir, I am getting errors, can you rewrite the code I posted?

Comment: Sorry, I was using Python 2 print syntax. Can you try it again please?

Comment: Getting errors also, I am just confused with what and where I should write, can you please rewrite my whole code and test it because I am still getting errors, and using two files as database, and I will be very thankful :)

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way to tell it to search the both txt files for fqWords list?

Comment: Well, with the last edit of yours, I am not getting any errors running the script, but I am getting a reflected error even though it could find the string in the database files, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to modify a list, use `tuple`. And for naming identifiers see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
To get difference of sequences, use `set`, f.e. `{1,2,3} - {2,3}` is `{1}`.
If you `open` same files within a loop, it get opened in every iteration, so better move them out of the loop.

```
import random

def get_line_with_words(lines, words):

    """returns list of lines if any of the words
       in any of the lines
    """
    return [(i, line.strip()) for i, line in enumerate(lines,1) if any(word in line for word in words)]

errors = ("Sorry, I don't understand.", "I don't get it")
ex_words = ('Who', 'How', 'What', 'How many', 'How much', 'am', 'is', 'are', '?', '!')
prefix = "Rel > "

with open("Database.txt") as db, open("CodeDB.txt") as cdb:
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input("> ")
        uq_words = user_input.split()
        fq_words = frozenset(uq_words) - frozenset(ex_words)

        res1 = get_line_with_words(db, fq_words)
        res2 = get_line_with_words(cdb, fq_words)

        if res1 and res2:
            for n, line in res1 + res2:
                print('{} {} {}'.format(prefix, n, line)
            break

        print('{} {}'.format(prefix, random.choice(errors)))
        db.seek(0)
        cdb.seek(0)
```